# Why am I getting an infinite loop in this model in java?

Tags: java

```
iHeight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your height in inches?");
boolean valid = false;
do {
    try {
        cHeight = Double.parseDouble(iHeight);
        valid = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number, \nplease re-enter your height");
    }           
} while(! valid);
```

Comment: `iHeight` always produces NFE. You are using the same value through out the iteration of your loop. I am sure you don't want to do this.

Comment: Probably because the `iHeight` value is never changed inside the loop.

Comment: Line `valid = true` is not executed if exception thrown from parseDouble. The outcome depends on what is in iHeight: if iHeight is parsed without exception, then you will not encounted infinite loop, else... the infinite loop. :)

Comment: If `Double.parseDouble(iHeight)`  throw `NumberFormatException`. `valid` is `false`, Then it will run your while loop continuously. Since  `iHeight` is not change inside the loop. This will run infinity.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume `Double.parseDouble(iHeight)` does throw a `NumberFormatException` and you catch it. Since the exception is thrown before you set `valid = true`, valid is never changed, so you will continue to loop. Now since your loop never changes the value of `iHeight` the same exception will be thrown every time you iterate through the loop, so you end up with an infinite loop.

One way to fix this is to have the user enter their height *inside* the loop, to give them a chance to fix their invalid input if an exception is thrown:

```
//you've already declared the variables iHeight and cHeight somewhere above here
boolean valid = false;
do {
    iHeight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your height in inches?");

    try {
        cHeight = Double.parseDouble(iHeight);
        valid = true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number, \nplease re-enter your height");
    }           
} while(!valid);
```

Answer (score 2):

First time if you enter valid height then your loop will work as expected. But first time if you enter invalid height then NFE is thrown and your valid indicator is false. So it will iterate it again and as you are not reading height again you will end up in infinite loop (it will follow above steps again and again).

So you need to move `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` part inside while loop. Try this code.

```
boolean valid = false;
do {
    iHeight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your height in inches?");
    try {
        cHeight = Double.parseDouble(iHeight);
        valid = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        valid = false; // This line is not necessary but you can add it to make it more readable.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number, \nplease re-enter your height");
    }
} while(!valid);
```